# Is there any method to display a pre-rendered font instead of displaying Unicode?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

I am working on a project which I need to display Unicode characters. I need to display Sinhala language in my application. But most of the mobile phone brands don't support that language. But the text displaying method that used in Facebook lite app display that language in any device.

Example Official Facebook app

[image: Official app]

Facebook lite app

[image: Facebook lite app]

What have they used to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display Sinhala in Android without setting a font. You can use this simple method,

```
Html.fromHtml("ගිරි දුර්ග සංසාරේ...").toString(); //Return as String
```

Hope this helps somebody as it helped to me.